# Проблема чтения изображений в цикле в Python

Tags: python, обработка-изображений

Я новичок в питоне, не понимаю, почему в моем коде считывается только первое фото, дальше всё правильно разрезается на строчки, но остальные фотографии не считывает в цикле.

```
def str_crop():

    for j in range(constants.num):
        img=Image.open("img/photo%s.jpg" % j)

        for i in range(constants.string):
            width = img.size[0]
            height = img.size[1]
            const_height = height / constants.string
            left = 0
            top = const_height * i
            right = width
            bottom = height - (height - (const_height + (const_height * i)))

            line = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            line.save("line%s.jpg" % i, "JPEG")
str_crop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас просто пишется всё в одни и те же файлы в этой строке:

```
line.save("line%s.jpg" % i, "JPEG")
```

Надо в название записываемого файла и `j` тоже поместить, чтобы писалось в разные файлы для разных `j`.

Например так:

```
line.save("line%s-%s.jpg" % (j,i), "JPEG")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы очень помогли)